# awk quoting program text

Tags: command-line, bash, scripts, awk

I just came across a gotcha in awk, and I would like to know if anyone can explain to me why this happens.

The following 2 lines behave differently if I run:

```
# grep -Rl BASE_DIR --exclude-dir=.svn * | awk -F "/" '{print $1}'
```

I get (as expected) just the first directory of the path to files containing BASE_DIR.

However, if I run it like this:

```
# grep -Rl BASE_DIR --exclude-dir=.svn * | awk -F="/" "{print $1}"
```

**EDIT:**

`-F="/"` and `-F "/"` don't make a difference on my tests. the second command has been updated to show this

*as suggested by glenn jackman on the answer I changed the command to:*

```
# grep -Rl BASE_DIR --exclude-dir=.svn * | awk -F "/" "{print $1}"
```

*and got the exact same flawed result*

**End of EDIT**

I get the full path to files containing BASE_DIR, I tried escaping the program text so it would be `"{print \$1}"` in case this was the issue, but I got the same results.

Can anybody enlighten me as to what the problem is here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the first example, you're doing: `awk -F "/"`
In the next example, you're doing: `awk -F="/"`

So the field separator is different: you're using the two character string `=/` as the field separator

---

Ah, I don't know why I didn't see this before: you're using the wrong quotes:

```
# grep -Rl BASE_DIR --exclude-dir=.svn * | awk -F "/" "{print $1}"
------------------------------------------------------^
```

The double quotes around the awk program means that the shell will substitute the variable `$1` **before** handing the program to awk. Most likely, in the shell, `$1` is empty, so awk sees this: `{print }`

Use single quotes instead.

Comment: nope, that's not it, I just changed it to test and still failed